# Getting Devise token authentication to return unauthorized message when using invalid token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am building an API using Rails 3.2.8 and I am using token based authentication.
In the beginning of all controller files I have this:

```
before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

This works very nice when I pass a valid token (user is logged in) but if I pass an invalid token it does nothing. I was expecting it to say unauthorized or something and stop all further processing of the controller file.

How can I do this?

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
def current_user
  @current_user
end

def verify_authenticity_token
  token = request.env["HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
  @current_user = User.where(authentication_token: token).first if token.present?
  unless token && current_user.present?

    #unauthorized logic here. Error or smth. other

  end
end
```